# Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section crash the using section

Tags: tableview, delete-row

I have a tableView display array data in expandable sections. When editing (delete), I have no problem to remove the element from array, but when update tableView, program crashes with error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update"

Here're my data model:

```
struct Trade {
var id: Int
var date: Date
var symbol: String
var qty: Double
var price: Double
}

trades = [Trade]()

struct SymbolSection {
  var symbol: String
  var trades: [Trade]
}
```

...

Here's my code for GroupBy (in viewDidLoad{}):

```
let groupBySymbol = Dictionary(grouping: trades, by: \.symbol)
    //put it in data model (array) groupBySymbol
    self.sections = groupBySymbol.map {(Key, Value) in
        return SymbolSection(symbol: Key, trades: Value)
    }
```

...

Here's code for editingStyle:

```
trades.remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

...

spent 3 days with no solution. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I thing your object is remove from array, you just need to reload your tableview.

Replace

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

with

```
tableView.reloadData()
```